# Max Count Query

Tags: mysql, sql, qsqlquery

This is my table and the table name is "ad_publisher_details". I want to find the maximum publisher company name means the company name who has most number of rows. Can anyone help?

Table:-

```html
<table>
  
  <thead>
    <th>
        ad_id
      </th>
    <th>
      publisher_name
      </th>
    <th>
      publisher_company
      </th>
    </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        1
        </td>
      <td>
        bikroy manager
        </td>
      <td>
        bikroy.com
        </td>
      </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        2
        </td>
      <td>
        olx manager
        </td>
      <td>
        olx.com
        </td>
      </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        3
        </td>
      <td>
        microsoft manager
        </td>
      <td>
        microsoft bangladesh
        </td>
      </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        4
        </td>
      <td>
        microsoft manager
        </td>
      <td>
        microsoft bangladesh
        </td>
      </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        5
        </td>
      <td>
        marketing manager
        </td>
      <td>
        land rover
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  
  </table>
```

After SQL query it will return only the publisher_company value "Microsoft Bangladesh". As it has the most row.

Comment: Can you share the query you've tried?

Comment: I think you are laying the framework for solving this on your own. Keep moving forward

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: You have to provide some db schama and data. Something like this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5c2bd/3)

Comment: I am using MySQL. @Bohemian

Answer (score 1):

You should:

1. `GROUP BY` publisher
2. `ORDER BY` number of rows, in descending order.
3. `LIMIT` the results to single row.

In other words you can do:

```
SELECT publisher_company
 FROM ad_publisher_details
 GROUP BY publisher_company
 ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
 LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

And at last i found the solution. I have to do a lot more php code to do so. Here is my solution.

```
<?php
                                            $i=0;
                                            $j=0;
                                            $br_temp=0;
                                            $query1="SELECT publisher_company FROM ad_publisher_details WHERE 1";
                                            $result1=mysql_query($query1,$dbs);
                                            while($row1=mysql_fetch_array($result1))
                                            {
                                                $publisher_company[$i]=$row1['publisher_company'];
                                                $i++;
                                            }
                                            for($i=0;$i<count($publisher_company);$i++)
                                            {
                                                $temp2= $publisher_company[$i];
                                                $query2="SELECT COUNT(ad_id) AS count_ad FROM ad_publisher_details WHERE publisher_company='$temp2'";
                                                $result2=mysql_query($query2,$dbs);
                                                while($row2=mysql_fetch_array($result2))
                                                {
                                                    $most_ad[$j]=$row2['count_ad'];
                                                    $j++;
                                                }
                                            }
                                            $highest_ad = max($most_ad);
                                            for($i=0;$i<count($publisher_company);$i++)
                                            {
                                                $i_temp = $publisher_company[$i];
                                                $query3="SELECT COUNT(ad_id) AS match_ad FROM ad_publisher_details WHERE publisher_company='$i_temp'";
                                                $result3=mysql_query($query3,$dbs);
                                                while($row3=mysql_fetch_array($result3))
                                                {
                                                    if($highest_ad==$row3['match_ad'])
                                                    {
                                                        echo $i_temp;
                                                        $br_temp=1;
                                                        break;
                                                    }
                                                    if($br_temp==1)
                                                    {
                                                        break;
                                                    }
                                                }
                                                if($br_temp==1)
                                                {
                                                    break;
                                                }
                                            }

                                            ?>
```

Comment: This is a terrible solution. Use the query in the other answer.